# Null values from Columns

Tags: c#, winforms

I have multiple columns of a table from my database. I want to check if a certain column has null values or not. I used this code but it only works for the first one, and not the second.

```
if (!read.IsDBNull(3))
{
  lblInc3.Visible = true;
  txtInc3.Visible = true;
  lblInc3.Text = read["Income3"].ToString();
}
else if (!read.IsDBNull(4))
{
  lblInc4.Visible = true;
  txtInc4.Visible = true;
  lblInc4.Text = read["Income4"].ToString();
} 
else 
{
  txtInc3.Visible = false;
  txtInc4.Visible = false;
}
```

I just want the logic to execute if multiple columns don't have null values. If it has null values then the textboxes should not be visible.

**EDIT:**

```
      try
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
            sqlCon.Open();

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Allowance", sqlCon);

            SqlParameter income1 = new SqlParameter("@Income1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            com.Parameters.Add(income1);
            income1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            SqlParameter income2 = new SqlParameter("@Income2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            com.Parameters.Add(income2);
            income2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            SqlParameter income3 = new SqlParameter("@Income3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            com.Parameters.Add(income3);
            income3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            SqlParameter income4 = new SqlParameter("@Income4", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            com.Parameters.Add(income4);
            income4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            SqlParameter income5 = new SqlParameter("@Income5", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            com.Parameters.Add(income5);
            income5.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            SqlDataReader read = com.ExecuteReader();

            while (read.Read())
            {
                bool threeBool = !read.IsDBNull(1) ? true : false;

                lblInc1.Visible = threeBool;
                txtInc1.Visible = threeBool;
                lblInc1.Text = threeBool ? read["Income1"].ToString() : string.Empty;


                bool fourBool = !read.IsDBNull(4) ? true : false;

                lblInc4.Visible = fourBool;
                txtInc4.Visible = fourBool;
                lblInc4.Text = fourBool ? read["Income4"].ToString() : string.Empty;

                /*if (!read.IsDBNull(1))
                {
                    lblInc1.Visible = true;
                    txtInc1.Visible = true;
                    lblInc1.Text = read["Income1"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtInc1.Visible = false;
                }

                if (!read.IsDBNull(2))
                {
                    lblInc2.Visible = true;
                    txtInc2.Visible = true;
                    lblInc2.Text = read["Income2"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtInc2.Visible = false;
                }

                if (!read.IsDBNull(3))
                {
                    lblInc3.Visible = true;
                    txtInc3.Visible = true;
                    lblInc3.Text = read["Income3"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtInc3.Visible = false;
                }

                if (!read.IsDBNull(4))
                {
                    lblInc4.Visible = true;
                    txtInc4.Visible = true;
                    lblInc4.Text = read["Income4"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtInc4.Visible = false;
                }

                if (!read.IsDBNull(5))
                {
                    lblInc5.Visible = true;
                    txtInc5.Visible = true;
                    lblInc5.Text = read["Income5"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtInc5.Visible = false;
                }*/
            } catch (Exception ex) {
               throw;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this, I hope this helps (I did not test this :) ).

Edited: based on your comments I believe this is what you want.

```
 bool threeBool = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(read["Income3"].ToString());

  lblInc3.Visible = threeBool ;
  txtInc3.Visible = threeBool ;
  lblInc3.Text = threeBool  ? read["Income3"].ToString() : string.empty;


  bool fourBool = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(read["Income4"].ToString());

  lblInc4.Visible = fourBool ;
  txtInc4.Visible = fourBool ;
  lblInc4.Text = fourBool ? read["Income4"].ToString() : string.empty;
```

Comment: Whats not working? show us the code where you are setting up your reader. Is the columns really DBNUll or are they empty strings?

Comment: what is the error?
also shorter: replace "bool threeBool = !read.IsDBNull(3) ? true : false;" with "bool threeBool = !read.IsDBNull(3);"
And same for fourBool

Comment: In the database, my columns allows null values. I want to hide textboxes if the value from database column is empty

Comment: @Ben Van Hees I go back and forth about that, some people get confused with the shorter version. The reverse logic and all where false is true.

Comment: replace your bool threeBool with:
bool threeBool = !(read.IsDBNull(3) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["Income3"]))
and fourBool with
bool fourBool = !(read.IsDBNull(4) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["Income4"]))

Comment: @deepz what database type some send dbNull some send empty string in that case you may look at what the database is sending null or "". If it is empty string then string.IsNullOrEmpty(read["Income3"].ToString()) would be the right test.

Comment: string.IsNullOrEmpty(read["Income3"])
     Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: In the old days of mine, I used to write some thing like this `bool x = a > b ? false : true;` :), that followed me some times when programming until I realized it was a little ridiculous because I could write it straight as `bool x = !(a > b);` Youv'e made me miss my those days :)

Comment: @King King :) I find myself making every thing shorter as I learn.

Comment: @N4TKD yes that worked!!! Thank you so much. This worked:  string.IsNullOrEmpty(read["Income3"].ToString()));

Comment: Great please mark it as the right answer I need the points :)

Answer (score 5):

It's not working for the second one because you're using an `else-if` and the statement is being short-circuited after the first comparison evaluates to true.  Implement a second `if` instead. e.g.

```
if (!read.IsDBNull(3))
{
  lblInc3.Visible = true;
  txtInc3.Visible = true;
  lblInc3.Text = read["Income3"].ToString();
} else
{
   txtInc3.Visible = false;
}

if (!read.IsDBNull(4))
{
  lblInc4.Visible = true;
  txtInc4.Visible = true;
  lblInc4.Text = read["Income4"].ToString();
}  else
{
   txtInc4.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: textboxes are still visible even if the value from database is null

Comment: I simply rearranged your existing logic -- I've updated my example with what I *think* you want.

Comment: Have you stepped through it to evaluate why it's not working?

Comment: Impossible.  There are other factors coming into play then.  Based on the code snippet above, if your values for column `3` or `4` are null, the corresponding else will *always* be hit.

Comment: @deepz the code should work as you want, what is your actual problem?

Comment: Problem is that when the value from database is empty, say Inc3 is empty then txtInc3 is visible. I do not want it to be visible when it is empty.

Comment: @deepz Then add another qualifier, e.g.  `!read.IsDBNull(3) && read["Income3"] != "")`

Comment: @deepz you have only some textboxes but put them together in a while loop to change their visibility, I think their visibility will depend on the last record (which the while loop checks out). I think you want to hide/show the textboxes by the current selection. In that case you should add your code in some selection changed event handler such as `SelectionChanged`,... and show/hide your textboxes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Else parts, if the first one is True, Else parts are skipped...

```
if (!read.IsDBNull(3))
{
  lblInc3.Visible = true;
  txtInc3.Visible = true;
  lblInc3.Text = read["Income3"].ToString();
}

if (!read.IsDBNull(4))
{
  lblInc4.Visible = true;
  txtInc4.Visible = true;
  lblInc4.Text = read["Income4"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: I also want to hide my textboxes if there are null values